# Tornado: Different methods in same class in routes

Tags: python, tornado

I'm pretty new in Tornado. Can I use something like below?

**Class**

```
class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        return self.render("home.html")

    def login(self):
        return self.render("login.html")
```

**Routes**

```
(r"/", HomeHandler),
(r"/login", HomeHandler.login, dict(db=db)),
```

This is not working. I tried to use `HomeHandler.login()`, but am not sure how to pass the required references (which should be similar to self).

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado uses the concept of "handlers", which, well, handle requests at a certain path. Handlers are classes. Internally Tornado selects a method from these classes corresponding to HTTP verb used in the request.

In your case, you have 2 paths: `/` and `/login`, let's call them "Home" and "Login' respectively. Now, you need to have 2 handlers: `HomeHandler` and `LoginHandler` and assign them to corresponding routes...

Routes:

```
(r"/", HomeHandler),
(r"/login", LoginHandler, {"db": db})
```

Handler classes:

```
class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        # Will work for GET yoursite.com/, e.g. when opened in a browser
        # The next line will render a template and return it to the browser
        self.render("home.html")


class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):

    def initialize(self, db):
        # That `db` from route declaration is passed as an argument
        # to this Tornado specific method
        self.db = db

    def get(self):
        # Will work for GET yoursite.com/login, e.g. when opened in a browser
        # You may use self.db here
        # The next line will render a template and return it to the browser
        self.render("login.html")

    def post(self):
        # Will work for POST yoursite.com/login, e.g. when the data
        # from the form on the Login page is sent back to the server
        # You may use self.db here
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. Tornado chooses which method to call based on the HTTP request (`get`, `post`, etc), so it is not possible to specify an alternative method in the routing table. Use different classes instead (probably with a common base class).